Geometrical interpretation of Cauchy-Riemann conditions as commutativity of Jacobian and complex structure
According to this wiki page on Cauchy Riemann equations, it says that the Cauchy Riemann equations are equivalent to commutativity of the complex structure $$\Omega=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\1 &0\end{pmatrix}$$ with the Jacobian of the transformation $f(z)$ i.e. $$J=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix}$$ which can be easily verified algebraically by explicitly computing the commutator $~[J,\Omega]$ and setting it to zero. But I wanted to get a geometrical interpretation/viewpoint/intuition on why analyticity implies preservation of complex structure by the Jacobian map. From wikipedia, I could find that

this interpretation is useful in symplectic geometry, where it is the starting point for the study of pseudoholomorphic curves.

I do not understand this either and wiki doesn't cite any article/book. Does anybody happen to know about a reference on this viewpoint? In short, why should I expect that the complex structure is preserved by the map (or it preserved by the Jacobian??) if the map is analytic?

Complex-differentiability is about approximating a function by a complex-linear map. Real-differentiability is about approximations by a real-linear map. So, the question of when a real-differentiable function is complex-differentiable is reduced to the following linear algebra question:

Given two (say finite-dimensional) complex vector spaces $V,W$, and a mapping $T:V\to W$ which is $\Bbb{R}$-linear (for the underlying real vector space structure of $V,W$), what are the necessary and sufficient conditions to ensure $T$ is also $\Bbb{C}$-linear?

Well, for an $\Bbb{R}$-linear map to be $\Bbb{C}$-linear, it is necessary and sufficient that for all $v\in V$, we have $T(iv)=iT(v)$, in other words, $T$ needs to commute with multiplication by $i$.
In terms of complex structures, what does this mean? Well, $V$ is a complex vector space, so we can now define $J_V:V\to V$ as $J_V(v):=iv$, i.e $J_V$ is multiplication by $i$. Similarly, we can define $J_W$ on $W$. Note that both $J_V$ provides a complex structure on the underlying real vector space $V_{\Bbb{R}}$, and likewise for $(W_{\Bbb{R}},J_W)$. We can now answer the above question as follows: an $\Bbb{R}$-linear map $T:V_{\Bbb{R}}\to W_{\Bbb{R}}$ actually comes from a $\Bbb{C}$-linear map $T:V\to W$ if and only if
\begin{align}
T\circ J_V=J_W\circ T.
\end{align}
In the special case $V=W$, we can just write $J$ for the complex structure and succinctly write this equation as $[T,J]=0$.

By fixing bases, you can extract a corresponding matrix equation. Slightly more explicitly, let’s say $\dim_{\Bbb{C}}V=n,\dim_{\Bbb{C}}W=m$. Given a $\Bbb{C}$-ordered-basis $\beta_V=\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$ for $V$, you get a corresponding $\Bbb{R}$-ordered-basis $\beta_{V_{\Bbb{R}},1}=\{v_1,\dots, v_n, iv_1,\dots, iv_n\}$ or another popular ordering choice is $\beta_{V_{\Bbb{R}},2}=\{v_1,iv_1,\dots, v_n,iv_n\}$. You can do a similar thing on $W$. Then, relative to these choices of bases, you get the corresponding matrix equation
\begin{align}
[T]\cdot [J_V]&=[J_W]\cdot [T].
\end{align}
Here, $[T]\in M_{2m\times 2n}(\Bbb{R})$, $[J_V]\in M_{2n\times 2n}(\Bbb{R})$ and $[J_W]\in M_{2m\times 2m}(\Bbb{R})$. Note that the choice of ordering of bases will give you slightly different matrix representations for the complex structures (see some remarks here).
In the case $n=m=1$, this just means you’ll have a single non-zero vector $v\in V$ which spans $V$. The matrix representation of the $\Bbb{R}$-linear map $J_V:V_{\Bbb{R}}\to V_{\Bbb{R}}$ relative to the ordered basis $\{v,iv\}$ is
\begin{align}
[J_V]&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0& -1\\
1&0
\end{pmatrix}=\Omega.
\end{align}
Similarly, we have $[J_W]=\Omega$. So, if we have the matrix-representation of $T:V_{\Bbb{R}}\to W_{\Bbb{R}}$ relative to $\{v,iv\}$ and $\{w,iw\}$ is $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$, then we get that the condition for $T$ to be $\Bbb{C}$-linear is
\begin{align}
A\cdot\Omega=\Omega\cdot A,
\end{align}
i.e $[A,\Omega]=0$. If you work it out, this says the matrix $A$ must actually equal $\begin{pmatrix}a&-c\\c&a\end{pmatrix}$.

Granted, none of this was a geometric explanation, what I really want to stress is that complex-differentiability is by definition the requirement of having a complex-linear approximation. Everything else is literally just linear algebra to see what this condition of complex-linearity entails. In particular, the Cauchy-Riemann equations are also just a trivial consequence of complex-linearity. In typical presentations, people make it seem like Cauchy-Riemann equations are the ‘fundamental’ thing, but I think it’s much better to look at it the other way around; they’re just the algebraic conditions forced upon you once you write out the condition of complex-linearity explicitly in terms of real/imaginary parts (see the link above).
